# How do I get a simple widget to respond to an IconButton?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a simple Text widget inside a SizedBox respond to taps on IconButtons in the AppBar. I copied the paradigm (or so I thought) of an earlier example of having a GridView update (provided by the SO community). In this current app, the current level is displayed. When the plus sign icon is tapped, the level should increment. When the replay icon is tapped, the level should be reset to 1.

During debugging, I found that the level passed to Level_Indicator was changing as expected. But in Level_Indicator_State, the value in level was always 1; it never incremented nor did it reset.

Code follows. Would someone please point out what I've done wrong? Thanks

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
// ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class Level_Indicator extends StatefulWidget {
  final int level;

  Level_Indicator(this.level, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override // Level_Indicator
  Level_Indicator_State createState() => Level_Indicator_State(level);
} // class Level_Indicator

class Level_Indicator_State extends State<Level_Indicator> {
  final int level;

  Level_Indicator_State(this.level);

  @override // Level_Indicator_State
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 24.0,
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              '$level',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 24.0,
              ) ,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
} // class Level_Indicator_State

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyApp_State();
  }
} // class MyApp

class MyApp_State extends State<MyApp> {
  int level = 1;

  void increment_level ( ){
    level++;
    setState(() {});
  } // increment_level

  void reinitialize() {
    level = 1;
    setState(() {});
  } // reinitialize

  @override // class MyApp_State
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Level Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Level Demo'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                increment_level();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.replay),
              onPressed: () {
                reinitialize();
              },
            ),
          ]
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:
            Level_Indicator(level)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} // class MyApp_State
```

Comment: Problem explanation was clear and able to solve the problem as the entire code was given. Good job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Why `Level_Indicator` is a Stateful Widget? It is just displaying what is given to it. **No state to handle**. Make it stateless.

   ```
   class Level_Indicator extends StatelessWidget {
     final int level;

     Level_Indicator(this.level);

     @override // Level_Indicator_State
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       print("level state");
       print("${level}");
       return Row(
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
         children: [
           SizedBox(
             width: 24.0,
             child: Container(
               child: Text(
                 '${level}',
                 style: TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.blue,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                   fontSize: 24.0,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ],
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. Let's say we want `Level_Indicator` to be **Stateful** for some reason. In this case also `level` is not a `state` variable of `Level_Indicator_State`. So use it as `widget.level` like below.

   ```
   class Level_Indicator extends StatefulWidget {
     final int level;

     Level_Indicator(this.level, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

     @override // Level_Indicator
     Level_Indicator_State createState() => Level_Indicator_State(level);
   } // class Level_Indicator

   class Level_Indicator_State extends State<Level_Indicator> {
     Level_Indicator_State();

     @override // Level_Indicator_State
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Row(
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
         children: [
           SizedBox(
             width: 24.0,
             child: Container(
               child: Text(
                 '${widget.level}',
                 style: TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.blue,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                   fontSize: 24.0,
                 ) ,
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ],
       );
     }
   } // class Level_Indicator_State // class Level_Indicator_State
   ```

Comment: I decided to use your second option. I had to change the following line Level_Indicator_State createState() => Level_Indicator_State(level); to eliminate the level parameter like so Level_Indicator_State createState() => Level_Indicator_State(); Thank you

Comment: Cool. I forgot to remove that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a `level` attribute in *both* the `Level_Indicator` StatefulWidget as well as the `Level_Indicator_State` class.

You don't need to pass this from Level_Indicator to Level_Indicator_State class via the constructor. You can just call `widget.level` from Level_Indicator_State.

This also means that **Level_Indicator does not need to be a Stateful class**. You can simplify this by just making it a Stateless class (since you are not changing the state from within this widget. You are creating new ones from MyApp_State.

**Changing the Level_Indicator to a stateless widget may resolve this issue** due to some non-obvious gotchas in the StatefulWidget lifecycle.

Read the [State classes documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) for more information (especially for widgets of the same runtimeType and key).

For more complex cases where you want to increment a counter (change state) from outside of a StatefulWidget (and not have that state maintained inside its state class) you will want to have some kind of ValueNotifier or Stream to do this rather than just passing the values in.

Comment: Thank you for your help.